# display timespan nicely

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, timespan

Excuse the rough code, I'm trying to display the duration of videos given the time in seconds.
 I've had a go below but it's not working properly.

I want it to just display nicely - i.e should display 9m:59s not 09m:59s.

If hours are zero dont display hours, if minutes are zero dont display minutes.

```
public static string GetTimeSpan(int secs)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs);

    string answer;
    if (secs < 60)
    {
        answer = string.Format("{0:D2}s", t.Seconds);
    }
    else if (secs < 600)//tenmins
    {
        answer = string.Format("{0:m}m:{1:D2}s", t.Minutes, t.Seconds);

    }
    else if (secs < 3600)//hour
    {
        answer = string.Format("{0:mm}m:{1:D2}s", t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
    }
    else
    {
        answer = string.Format("{0:h}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s",
                                    t.Hours,
                                    t.Minutes,
                                    t.Seconds);
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: so what is your question? or what do you expect to happen and what does happen? please do not expect me to guess :)

Comment: the question is display time duration nicely given the seconds. if hours are zero dont display hours, if minutes are zero dont display minutes, also would want in format 9m:59s not 09m:59s for single figure minutes.

Comment: Your format strings are wrong, there is no "m" or "h" specifier.See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). You are just dealing with "numbers" not "minutes/seconds"! Also you do not need to explicitly specify "2 places" for values > 10.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Something like:

```
public static string PrintTimeSpan(int secs)
{
   TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs);
   string answer;
   if (t.TotalMinutes < 1.0)
   {
     answer = String.Format("{0}s", t.Seconds);
   }
   else if (t.TotalHours < 1.0)
   {
     answer = String.Format("{0}m:{1:D2}s", t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
   }
   else // more than 1 hour
   {
     answer = String.Format("{0}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s", (int)t.TotalHours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
   }

   return answer;
}
```

Comment: Why use `t.TotalHours` when you can use `t.Hours`?

Comment: @FandiSusanto If the timespan is "1 day and 2 hours", TotalHours will return 26, Hours will return 2.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can simplify this by removing the "D2" aspect of the format and then you won't need a special case for the under ten minutes option. Basically just using

```
string.Format("{0}m:{1}s", t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
```

will get you one or two digits as required. So your final case is:

```
string.Format("{0}h:{1}m:{2}s", t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
readonly static Char[] _colon_zero = { ':', '0' };
// ...

var ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
String s = ts.ToString("h\\:mm\\:ss\\.ffff").TrimStart(_colon_zero);
```

> ```
> .0321
> 6.0159
> 19.4833
> 8:22.0010
> 1:04:2394
> 19:54:03.4883
> ```

Answer (score 2):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) try this:

```
if (secs < 60)
{
    answer = t.Format("s");
}
else if (secs < 600)//tenmins
{
    answer = t.Format("m:s");
}
// ...
```