# Format string for a TimeSpan that adds the days to the string only if they are non-zero

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting, timespan

I need to set the Format of a TimeSpan such that days are displayed only if nonzero.

Right now I'm using `@"d' days, 'hh\:mm"`, which will format a `new TimeSpan(1,2,3,4,5)` as `1 days, 02:03`, but it will also format a `new TimeSpan(0,2,3,4,5)` as `0 days, 02:03`, which is not what I want - I want only `02:03` in that case.

The problem is that the exact same format will be applied to all of the time spans, which is the difference between my question and [display timespan nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292014/display-timespan-nicely), so I can't use (pseudo)code like this:

```
if (hasDays) {
     format = @"dd' days, 'hh\:mm";
} else {
     format = @"hh\:mm";
}
```

I can't use that, the condition must somehow be encoded in the format string itself. Is it possible to achieve that?

*Please note: I am not interested in solutions that do not involve using the exact same format string. If it's impossible then an answer stating so is sufficient.*

Comment: " If it's impossible then an answer stating so is sufficient." There is not a single format string that accomplishes what you want - format strings cannot contain conditional logic.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks. I was asking just in case, because regex for example have the | (OR) operator built-in so who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional formatting is not possible using a format string; but depending on the control which shows data, you can use some solutions to perform conditional formatting.

---

In Windows Forms, complex data-binding is supported by `ListBox`, `ComboBox`, `DataGridView` and `DataGrid`. In this post I'll show how you can perform conditional formatting for these controls in Windows Forms applications.

- **ListBox and ComboBox**

  Set `FormattingEnabled` to `true` and handle `Format` event. Use `e.Value` to get item value and set the formatted value.
- **DataGridView**

  Handle `CellFormatting` event. You can use `e.Value` to get cell value or set the formatted value.
- **DataGrid**

  You can create a custom `DataGridColumnStyle`, based on `DataGridTextBoxColumn` and override `GetColumnValueAtRow` and return formatted value.

### Example

In all below examples, I use a method to format value:

```
string FormatValue(object value)
{
    if (value is TimeSpan)
    {
        var time = (TimeSpan)value;
        if (time.TotalDays < 1.0)
            return time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
        else
            return time.ToString(@"d' days, 'hh\:mm");
    }
    return string.Format("{0}", value);
}
```

**ListBox and ComboBox**

```
void listBox_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    e.Value = FormatValue(e.Value);
}
```

**DataGridView**

```
void dg_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Value = FormatValue(e.Value);
}
```

**DataGrid**

```
//public class MyDataGridTextBoxColumn : DataGridTextBoxColumn
protected override object GetColumnValueAtRow(CurrencyManager source, int rowNum)
{
    var value = base.GetColumnValueAtRow(source, rowNum);
    return FormatValue(value);
}
```

You should use this column style for the column which you want to use this format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this only in an event like `DataGridView.CellFormatting`. Here you can give your cell an individual format.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx